# Can we create JPA Entities for database views?

Tags: java, jpa, olingo

I already have created JPA entities from database tables.

I would like to know if we can create JPA entities for database Views.

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it out? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is a [blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/mapping_jpa_entities_on_view) about it, from first page of a google search.